# in Rails is there an easy way to create a once per record event to take place in the future

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduler, resque, delayed-execution

Without using the the resque_scheduler gem, is there a way to set up a task to run  6 hours from right now.

I figured that a chron job would do me, but the whenever gem doesn't seem able to run whenever.. it seems set up to run often, but not at once. It also seems to require hard coding things.

In my old gig I'd have used delayed_job to accomplish this task, but we don't use that here, so I'm wondering.  If one has resque and the whenever gem in their code and not much else, is there an easy way to create one-offs.

---

Another example would be if a user creates a job and in 24 hours it has to be deleted from the system.  I would want to add a job to a queue (of some sort) that would delete the record.

Comment: I suppose one-off was wrongly used.  I mean that it happens once per task and not on specific times.. 6 hours from saving a record in my db I want to send the user info on that record and changes in related tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `rufus-scheduler` gem for this. with this gem you can run particular code after certain time interval it doesn't need any cron job to run the code.

If you want to run continuously :

Write code in your model directly (in a method) and put below code in your `production.rb/development.rb` file. One thing this function start calculating time/execution after you start your server and execute after certain time interval whatever you provided. (No cron needed)

```
config.after_initialize do
    Model.method
end
```

if you want to run for specific task :
Inside your code. Also no need for changes in environment files :

```
Rufus::Scheduler.singleton.in '6h' do
  #Codehere
end
```